# What's the best way to switch language resource files based on a querystring variable in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, culture, razor-2, resource-files

I'm using MVC 4 and razor views. We have an app that pulls from resource files. Currently there is only one set of resource files but we have a request to have some translations in parts of the site which will see some extra resource files for foreign languages come in.

Part of the application sends out referrals to users and in that referral there is the option to set the language to be shown (regardless of what the user-client is set too). This is going to be set on the querystring as `lang=ES`. We're referencing the resource variables in the view like this `@Resources.Templates.ReferralAcceptance.DefaultAcceptanceMessage`. If no lang value is available in the querystring I need to default to the cultureCode sent from the client, which if not available will fall back to the standard english version we have.

I'm new to resource files, particularly with MVC. What's the best way of me tackling this?

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I have done in the past:

In your `web.config` file, add the following setting:

```
  <system.web>
    <globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" />
  </system.web>
```

This will handle your **fallback** instance, where there is no language set in the query string.

---

Now to the controller to utilise the query string "lang" parameter:

(I usually would have the following code in a "BaseController" and have my controllers inherit from this.)

Add the following override method to your controller:

```
protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
    var culture = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["lang"];

    //!!Check to see if culture exists and is valid before setting the thread culture

    var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(culture);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;

    return base.BeginExecute(requestContext, callback, state);
}
```

This enables you to read the "lang" value in the query string and then use it to set the culture of the thread.  This should override any culture set by the `enableClientBasedCulture` setting.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a query string to specify the language, you'd better define a new route like `http://MyHost/Culture/Controller/Action/Id`.

There's a good explanation of what you need to do here in part 2 of this article:

[Creating a bilingual asp.net MVC application - Part 1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/181738/Creating-a-Bilingual-ASP-NET-MVC3-Application-Part)

[Creating a bilingual asp.net MVC application - Part 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/207602/Creating-a-Bilingual-ASP-NET-MVC3-Application-Part)